# Unable to configure Java Decompiler in Eclipse 2023-06

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, decompiler

I am trying to configure Java Decompiler in Eclipse 2023-06 in order to get into .class files from within JARs, where no sources are attached. For that, I have installed the Enhanced Class Decompiler 3.3.0 plugin from Eclipse Marketplace -

[image]

Following that I have restarted, quit and opened Eclipse multiple times. However, I don't see any new editor to be added under *Associated Editors* in this path, Windows -> Preference -> Editors -> File Associations. The available options don't work.

[image]

Also, I have tried searching *Decompiler* under Preference search, which in usual case, is supposed to be there under Java. But here in my case, nothing shows up -

[image]

Am I missing something here or is this indeed some issue currently present with this latest version of Eclipse?

Comment: What do you get when you click "Add..." in the "Associated editors" section

Comment: @greg-449 Clicking on Add I am able to see two types of editors to choose from - 1) Internal editors 2) External programs. Both have got a number of options under them. However, neither fits here. I assume, an Editor related with this Enhanced Class Decompiler should have been added there.

Comment: Does it show up in the installed software list (Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installation Software)? Try the install from the update site as described on the project page https://ecd-plugin.github.io/ecd/

Comment: Yes, they did show up in that software list (Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installation Software). Additionally, I installed it again both from the project page guided steps and directly doing a drag and drop of the installer in running Eclipse workspace. However, still no luck.
Just wanted to mention here, I am working in the Eclipse 2023-06 edition installed in a 64 bit Windows 11 system with JDK 17. Could this combination have anything to do with this issue?

Comment: You can report issues direct to the developers on the github site https://github.com/ecd-plugin/ecd/issues

Comment: I reported this on GitHub, got some suggestions as well. However, still no luck! 

Later, I tried installing Eclipse 2023-03 (just the previous version) and there this entire Decompiler plugin thing has worked in one shot! Looks like this is really an issue currently with the latest version i.e., Eclipse 2023-06 or at least for the combination that I had, Windows 11 64 Bit + JDK17 + Eclipse 2023-06, not sure.